# NP hard but not NPC

Tags: scheduling, np-complete, np, np-hard

I have seen couple of scheduling problem which says that the problem is NP hard. My question is that 
1)when we say a problem is NP hard does it mean that it is not in NP?because if it is NP we say the problem is NP complete.
I know that a problem is in NPC if
a)it is in NP
b)it is NP hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a problem is NP Hard, it may be in NP(then it's a NP complete), but it could also be not in NP. The following is a Venn diagram of these classes:

[image]